# How to get element by Index in Spark RDD (Java) not scala, python

Tags: java, python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I know the method `rdd.first()` which gives me the first element in an `RDD`.

Also, there is the method `rdd.take(num)` Which gives me the first `num` elements.

But isn't there a possibility to get an element by index?

Comment: order is of little importance when it comes to a distributed processing system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RDDs are not indexed, in majority of cases don't guarantee the order and don't support efficient single item access.

You can

- `zipWithIndex` and `filter`.
- `zipWithIndex`, swap elements and `lookup`.

but this is not advised, requires linear scan, and might have non-deterministic behavior.